# Gitlab CI/CD not picking up docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-image, gitlab-8

I am new to Gitlab CI/CD and hence this question might seem very basic to others.

I have created two jobs - one is picked up by GitlabRunner configured on a VM and other should run on specified docker image.

my .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
stages:

- build
- deploy

job1:

   stage: build

  script:
  - *do something*

tags:
  - matlab    # specific gitlab runner is configured for this tag

job2:

  image: *docker-image*   # this is the docker image i want to use

  stage: deploy

  script:
  - *do something*
```

I am observing that sometimes, GitLab CI/CD runs job2 also on VM configured for matlab tags.

This does seem unusual. Has anyone observed this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [job tag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#tags) is different from a [runner using tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#using-tags).

And you still need to:

> Prevent Runners with tags from picking jobs without tags
>
> You can configure a Runner to prevent it from picking jobs with tags when the Runner does not have tags assigned.
>   This setting can be enabled the first time you register a Runner and can be changed afterwards under each Runner's settings.
>
> To make a Runner pick tagged/untagged jobs:
>
> - Visit your project's Settings ➔ CI/CD
> - Find the Runner you wish and make sure it's enabled
> - Click the pencil button
> - Check the Run untagged jobs option
>     Click Save changes for the changes to take effect